# which design pattern to use to get the wanted functionality

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

I want to make a pure virtual class that other classes inherit and each class implements the same function but with different implementation:
let say I implement class Server

```
class Server
{
   Server();
   ~Server()=0;
   virtual void send(const std::string& string);
   virtual std::string receive();
};

class TcpServer:public Server
{
   TcpServer();
   ~TcpServer();
   void send(const std::string& string)
   {...}
   std::string receive(){...}
};

class UdpServer : public Server
{
    UdpServer ();
    ~UdpServer ();
    void send(const std::string& string)
    {...}
    std::string receive(){...}
};



main()
{
    Server* server = new TcpServer()/UdpServer;
}
```

What's this Design Pattern called? because I don't understand if it's Adapter or Composite or Facade and if you have a different idea of how to implement this behavior.

Comment: You forget one main point of polymophism in C++... That polymorphic functions needs to be `virtual`.

Comment: thank you i forgat to add this for the question

Comment: also if you want them to be pure virtual you should make each virtual function = 0;
like virtual void send(const std::string& string) = 0; (inside the server class)

Comment: Also, the destructor for `Server` needs to be `virtual` for the use case you are showing us.

Comment: ...and unless you want to force all child classes to implement a destructor, you could add a default implementation yourself (outside the class definition): `Server::~Server() {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategy pattern should be implemented for this use case. Check the link below for more information.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: Wouldn't it be more a Factory Pattern? Since the creation is not covered in the strategy

Comment: As I understood, the idea is to select type of server at runtime (polymorphism) hence server variant is substitutable by abstract class or interface in question. Hence Strategy pattern fits.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon no. The use case is not about how to create a server type, but to substitute a type of server at runtime based on parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean more towards Factory Pattern:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Since you go into TCP/ UDP you might also check out the  reactor pattern

Comment: the reactor pattern is not relevant to my case, I just gave the example for tcp\udp in my real case is to chose which 3rd party lib to use (and only in the beginning of the program)